# In French, how do you express the English construction "with someone doing ..."?

Tags: traduction, constructions, participe-présent

I wonder what is a commonly used equivalent of the English construction "with someone doing ...", as in "with your boss watching your every move".

> **Avec** ton chef **surveillant** tous tes faits et gestes, tu ne te sens pas mal à l'aise ?
>
> Ton chef **surveillant** tous tes faits et gestes, tu ne te sens pas mal à l'aise ?
>
> **Avec** ton chef **qui surveille** tous tes faits et gestes, tu ne te sens pas mal à l'aise ?

The 3rd one with "qui" would be unlikely in English: "with your boss who watches your every move". But does this "qui" construction work in French?

Comment: They're all understandable. The 1st two sound weird & like bad translations from English to me, they might be correct but personally I would only use the 3rd one.

Comment: @Laure I also have a feeling of strangeness from the first 2, but without really being able to put my finger on the problem. Would it be that present participle in French would usually introduce a statement rather than a question? *(‘Mon chef surveillant tous mes faits et gestes, je me sens mal à l'aise’* sounds quite okay to me...)

Comment: @Feelew Your sentence sounds better, but I would not use it. Can't say why though. There might be something in your question thing.

Comment: I don't agree that 1 and 2 sounds weird... it's a normal use of present participle. I would say they're even probably a bit more formal while the 3rd one is more casual. Note that it could be even more formal with the correct use of subject and verb inversion for asking a question, which nowadays indeed sounds weirder and weirder.

Comment: @Feelew Cet honorable Belge dit que le p. présent peut avoir la valeur d'une proposition subordonnée (ici ce serait la cause), en pratique il me semble que dans l'Hexagone on emploierait plutôt la relative.

Comment: @Feelew Je trouve pas que c'est tant le participe présent que l'espèce de trompe l'oeil _surveillant en chef_ ou _chef-surveillant_...  pour l'éviter il faudrait une incise, mais la phrase ne le permet pas...

Comment: @HydrangéacéeslesHydrangelles J'en viens à me demander si j'utilise même le participe présent non précédé de *«en»* dans mon discours quotidien. Je n'ai pu encore trouver un seul contre-exemple où je ne sentirais pas l'artificiel s'immiscer en mon discours. Une grande incertitude m'envahit: ce temps de verbe sans l'introducteur *«en»* serait-il aujourd'hui restreint au discours écrit ou à un discours oral préparé?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afin de vérifier si elles sont *correctes* vous pouvez les inverser comme suit :

> Tu ne te sens pas mal à l'aise avec ton chef surveillant tous tes faits et gestes  ?
>
> Tu ne te sens pas mal à l'aise, ton chef surveillant tous tes faits et gestes ?
>
> Tu ne te sens pas mal à l'aise avec ton chef qui surveille tous tes faits et gestes ?

La seconde reste compréhensible mais n'est vraiment pas commune, la première avec l'utilisation du participe présent est parfaitement correcte dans un contexte écrit et/ou soutenu.

La troisième est véritablement la plus commune, tout du moins en langage parlé.

Les propositions faites dans la réponse de @SdaliM en terme de différentes traductions sont également très acceptables, aussi bien à l'écrit qu'à l'oral.

Comment: Rusé et judicieux, l'inversion. Le malaise s'accentue pour moi pour le second exemple, mais la première sonne un peu mieux inversée et me semble presque correcte, quoique je ne l'utiliserais personnellement pas *(je me sentirais un peu mal à l'aise avec mon discours habituel si désinvolte par rapport aux rigueurs de notre langue* ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I think, as stated in the comments, that all three sentences are correct.

However, I want to propose less direct translations, if you only want a general meaning:

> - Tu ne te sens pas mal à l'aise avec ton chef toujours sur ton dos ?
> - Ça ne te dérange pas d'avoir ton chef qui te tient à l'œil ?

Answer (score 0):

Personnellement j'aurais utilisé "en train de".

> Ne te sens tu pas mal à l'aise avec ton chef **en train de** surveiller tout tes faits et gestes ?
>
> Avec ton chef **en train de** surveiller tout tes faits et gestes, ne te sens tu pas mal à l'aise ?
>
> Tu ne te sens pas mal à l'aise avec ton chef qui est **en train de** surveiller tous tes faits et gestes ?

Je pense que l'usage de "en train de" est faisable ici car il désigne l'action du chef à l'instant où le sujet travaille, et non pas l'instant où on pose la question.

D'autre part la formulation "Tu ne te sens pas mal à l'aise ?" ne me semble pas correcte car il s'agit d'une question, la formulation suivante me paraît plus correcte d'un point de vue grammatical :

> Ne te sens tu pas mal à l'aise ?